# How to bind both once and not once using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

How can I sucessfully do this?

```
ng-class="{'a':x, 'b':::y}"
```

Notice how I'm trying to bind only once with "y" but not with "x"

I also tried using multiple ng-class directives, like this:

`<div ng-class="{'a':x}" ng-class="::{'b':y}"></div>`

but doesn't work either.

Comment: please show more code context. We have no way to know if this could be done in controller or not

Comment: There is no point using 2 ng-class directives on the same eement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can only specify one-time binding syntax `::` at the beginning of the expression. Here your expression is an object literal and using `::` before the second key value results in an invalid syntax. You would have to split them up and probably place one section in the `class` expression (There is no point using 2 `ng-class` directives).

Example:

```
ng-class="{'a':x}" class="someclass {{::{true:'b'}[y]}}"
```

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)

> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. ....

```css
.a {
  color: green;
}
.b {
  color: blue;
}
.a.b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>

  <div ng-class="{'a':x}" class="{{::{true:'b'}[y]}}">Test</div>
  X->
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x">Y->
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="y">

</div>
```

Note: One time binding will keep the watch *until* it gets an non undefined value for the bound property. If the property value is available at the time view renders (i.e not asyncronous) you could just do

```
<div ng-class="{'a':x}" class="{{::y ? 'b': ''}}">Test</div>
```

as well.

Comment: this may be promising, let me give it a try